# How to access this XDocument with XML LINQ

Tags: c#, xml

I have the following descendants:

```
  <ReportItem Asset="111" ESN="111" Longitude="123" Latitude="123" MessageTime="2/16/2011" MessageTimeZone="CST" MessageTimeZoneGMTOffset="-360" SpeedUnit="Mph" Speed="111" Direction="West" Address="test" Name="testing" />
```

There are multiple of these in the same XDocument but I am looping through them with the following:

```
IEnumerable<XElement> elements = XData.Descendants("ReportItem");

                foreach (XElement element in elements)
```

I am then trying to assigning these to a business objects class that contains the same names.
I am wondering why this is not assigning them at all:

```
 foreach (XElement element in elements)
            {
                _dataPoints.AddRange((from datapoint in elements.Attributes("ReportItem")
                                      select new DataPoint()
                                      {
                                          Asset = element.Attribute("Asset").Value,
                                          ESN = element.Attribute("ESN").Value,
                                          Longitude = element.Attribute("Longitude").Value,
                                          Latitude = element.Attribute("Latitude").Value,
                                          MessageTime = element.Attribute("MessageTime").Value,
                                          MessageTimeZone = element.Attribute("MessageTimeZone").Value,
                                          MessageTimeZoneGMTOffset = element.Attribute("MessageTimeZoneGMTOffset").Value,
                                          MinutesIdle = element.Attribute("MinutesIdle").Value,
                                          Address = element.Attribute("Address").Value,
                                          Name = element.Attribute("Name").Value,
                                          TripDistance = element.Attribute("TripDistance").Value,
                                          TripDistanceUnit = element.Attribute("TripDistanceUnit").Value,
                                      }).ToList());
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are using the wrong variable - you should use the range variable but you are using the outer loop variable.

So this:

```
select new DataPoint()
{
   Asset = element.Attribute("Asset").Value,
   ..
```

should be

```
select new DataPoint()
{
  Asset = datapoint.Attribute("Asset").Value,
  ..
```

Also you do not need the outer loop in the first place, and the inner LINQ query goes over an attribute that doesn't exist - the whole thing should just be:

```
_dataPoints.AddRange((from datapoint in elements
                        select new DataPoint()
                        {
                            Asset = datapoint.Attribute("Asset").Value,
                            ESN = datapoint.Attribute("ESN").Value,
                            Longitude = datapoint.Attribute("Longitude").Value,
                            Latitude = datapoint.Attribute("Latitude").Value,
                            MessageTime = datapoint.Attribute("MessageTime").Value,
                            MessageTimeZone = datapoint.Attribute("MessageTimeZone").Value,
                            MessageTimeZoneGMTOffset = datapoint.Attribute("MessageTimeZoneGMTOffset").Value,
                            MinutesIdle = datapoint.Attribute("MinutesIdle").Value,
                            Address = datapoint.Attribute("Address").Value,
                            Name = datapoint.Attribute("Name").Value,
                            TripDistance = datapoint.Attribute("TripDistance").Value,
                            TripDistanceUnit = datapoint.Attribute("TripDistanceUnit").Value,
                        }).ToList());
```

Also note that you are using attributes that are not even defined in your XML (i.e. `MinutesIdle`, `TripDistance`, `TripDistanceUnit`). You either have test and handle null in this case or remove those from your `DataPoint` class. An example of handling null would be :

```
 MinutesIdle = (string)datapoint.Attribute("MinutesIdle") ?? "0",
```

Comment: This gives me an Object Not Set to instance of object exception

Comment: above code works for me tested using an anonymous class and dropping the non-existing attributes that you are using. You have to have a pre-existing `_dataPoint` variable initialized with an empty list of type `List<DataPoint>` of course.

Answer (score 0):

What is `elements.Attributes("ReportItem")` in your code supposed to do?

I think what you really want is this:

```
_dataPoints.AddRange(XData.Descendants("ReportItem").Select(element => 
                                      select new DataPoint(){
                                          Asset = element.Attribute("Asset").Value,
                                          ESN = element.Attribute("ESN").Value,
                                          Longitude = element.Attribute("Longitude").Value,
                                          Latitude = element.Attribute("Latitude").Value,
                                          MessageTime = element.Attribute("MessageTime").Value,
                                          MessageTimeZone = element.Attribute("MessageTimeZone").Value,
                                          MessageTimeZoneGMTOffset = element.Attribute("MessageTimeZoneGMTOffset").Value,
                                          MinutesIdle = element.Attribute("MinutesIdle").Value,
                                          Address = element.Attribute("Address").Value,
                                          Name = element.Attribute("Name").Value,
                                          TripDistance = element.Attribute("TripDistance").Value,
                                          TripDistanceUnit = element.Attribute("TripDistanceUnit").Value
                                      }));
```

Comment: Just get the attributes? Asset, ESN, Longitude, etc.

Comment: Well, that's not what it does as far as I can tell. Look closely at the sample code in the documentation, it filters the attribute names, not the element names. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341024.aspx